# Custom css styles in react-bootstrap not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Why is my custom css styles not working with react-bootstrap? I use npx create-react-app, node-sass and npm i react-bootstrap. What Am i missing?

Thanks!

Here is my sample files:

[image: file structure]

`index.js` code:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";



/*import here*/

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

custom scss

```
 body {
  background: #0b739c;
}

.login-form {
  background: white;

  h1 {
    /*styles here*/
  }

  form {
    input {
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

`login.js` code

```
import "./Login.module.scss";
/*code here*/

    const Login = () => {
      return (
        <Container fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Image src={LoginImage} alt="login image" />
              <h2>Bring all your friends to any network!</h2>
            </Col>
            <Col className="m-0 login-form">
              /*form code here*/
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      );
    };
    
    export default Login;
```

Sample output, custom styles not reflecting:

[image: Form UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue instead on `Login.module.scss`, change to the file to `Login.scss` and it works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It basically boils down to the following steps:

Download bootstrap using npm install react-bootstrap

1. Install SASS pre-processor (https://sass-lang.com/install)
2. Create a scss file for overriding bootstrap's _variables.scss (make sure the path to _functions.scss, _variables.scss, _mixins.scss and bootstrap.scss is correct

   ```
   @import "bootstrap/scss/functions"; 
   @import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
   @import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

   /* Your customizations here */

   $theme-colors: (
     primary: red;
    );

   @import "bootstrap";
   ```
3. Transpile your stylesheet.scss to stylesheet.css and add a reference to your head section like so: 
   https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203